# How to configure gemfire for spring cache manager without explicitly defining regions?

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have a spring application using spring caching based on Guava cache. Due to the high throughput demand and the write-behind functionality, we are now considering migration to Gemfire.
I am successful in configuration Gemfire as cache and is able to read and write from the cache. In all the configuration examples, the configuration requires defining of LocalRegionFactory as below:

```
    @Bean
    public Region<Long,Person> myPersonRegion(LocalRegionFactoryBean<Long, Person> personRegion) throws Exception {

        return personRegion.getObject();


    }

    @Bean
    public LocalRegionFactoryBean<Long, Person> personRegion(GemFireCache cache,AsyncEventQueue gemfireQueue) {
        LocalRegionFactoryBean<Long, Person> personRegion = new LocalRegionFactoryBean<>();
        personRegion.setCache(cache);
        personRegion.setClose(false);
        personRegion.setName("person");
        personRegion.setAsyncEventQueues(new AsyncEventQueue[]{gemfireQueue});
        personRegion.setPersistent(false);
        return personRegion;

    }
```

After the beans are defined, we can use @Cacheable(value="person"), @CacheEvict(value="person"). If we directly use a cache name, gemfire throws error that the cache is not defined.

Our experience with Guava ( or  Hazelcast, redis etc ) is that , we don't need to explicitly define the caches. It will be automatically  created by spring on first occurence.

Is there any way configure gemfire to also behave in the same way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**; not exactly.

I am not entirely certain your following statement is completely accurate either...

> Our experience with Guava ( or Hazelcast, redis etc ) is that , we don't need to explicitly define the caches.

For Hazelcast, I know this is not **true** from [recent experience](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/test/java/example/app/caching/provider/hazelcast/HazelcastJsr107Tests.java) (see [configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/test/java/example/app/caching/provider/hazelcast/HazelcastJsr107Tests.java#L62-L80), and specifically [this line](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/test/java/example/app/caching/provider/hazelcast/HazelcastJsr107Tests.java#L78)).  *Line 78* is absolutely necessary (in some shape or form, e.g. alternatively XML); without it, *Spring's* Cache Abstraction will throw an Exception.

Although I have not tested Redis as a caching provider, it does appear Redis can handle [dynamic `Cache` creation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/1.8.0.M1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.java#L119) (also [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/1.8.0.M1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.java#L98-L101)).

It is likely true that Guava, like the [`ConcurrentMapCacheManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.html) implementation, does not require pre-existing [`Caches`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) be explicitly defined since the `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` will [dynamically create the `Cache`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.java#L166-L174)( a `ConcurrentHashMap`) at runtime when requested [if NOT explicitly "named"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.java#L86-L94).  However, if the `Caches` are explicitly named in advance, then an Exception will be thrown if the `Cache` is not already defined (i.e. "named").

I have examples and tests of other caching providers [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/tree/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache) that illustrate different and rather unique UCs of *Spring's* Cache Abstraction in practice, identified by the test class or test case names.

However, in all Pivotal GemFire or Apache Geode test examples, you must explicitly create the Region that will serve as the "`Cache`" in *Spring's* caching infrastructure.  Although, SDG's `GemfireCacheManager` implementation will [dynamically create](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.8.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/GemfireCacheManager.java#L90-L93) the Spring `Cache` object (backed by the underlying Region) that is required by *Spring's*  AOP `CacheInterceptor`.

This results in the following, minimal, necessary configuration to enable caching with GemFire/Geode as the provider...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
class MyCachingApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyCachingApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  GemfireCacheManager cacheManager(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {
    GemfireCacheManager cacheManager = new GemfireCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCache(gemfireCache);
    return cacheManager;
  }

  // define all Region beans required by the application including Regions
  // used specifically in Spring's Cache Abstraction
}
```

Now, having said this, I have prototyped dynamic Region creation based on the Spring Cache Abstraction annotations (e.g. `@Cacheable`) used throughout the declared application [service] components as can be seen starting with this [test](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CachingWithGemFireUsingDynamicRegionCreationIntegrationTest.java).  Here is the [configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/spring/cache/CachingWithGemFireUsingDynamicRegionCreationIntegrationTest-context.xml).

As you can see, there are NO explicit bean definitions for the GemFire Regions that will serve as `Caches` in Spring's caching infrastructure.  Yet, the application's (test's) Spring `@Service` component does [make use of caching](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/service/ExampleCachingService.java#L35-L48).

Dynamic Region creation is accomplished by making use of a *Spring* [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) ([here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/config/CacheableAnnotationDynamicRegionCreationBeanPostProcessor.java)) and GemFire Functions (using SDG's Function annotation support) to dynamically create the Regions at runtime, during startup.  The Function execution is [defined here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/execute/OnMembersCreateRegionFunctionExecution.java), and the actual Function implementation is [defined here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/execute/RegionFunctions.java#L45-L59).

This example is pretty crude (i.e. does not handle custom Region configuation (e.g. eviction/expiration, persistence, overflow, etc) beyond `DataPolicy`) and is currently setup to handle the peer cache topology (i.e. the test application is a peer member/node in the GemFire DS).

However, it is pretty easy to extend this prototype to be used in a client/server topology, take into account all *Spring* and **JSR-107** caching annotations and allow more custom Region configuration.

In time, this maybe something I add to the SDG framework itself.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
John

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed explanation you have provided. I will be trying out the tests and BeatPostProcessor method. Few more points :
1. Hazelcast does support dynamic cache creation. Please find the below gist [link] (https://gist.github.com/sandheepgr/c715ce530a279b27a8144ef834c19918) . This was a test setup and never made it to production for us.
2. Is there a specific mode for write-behind configuration. I have defined writer and loader and it write immediately to db ( also possible using async) . But doesn't coalesce the data to write last update only.

Comment: Hi @Sandheep- I am still skeptical that Hazelcast will dynamically create Caches.  It needs at least a DistributedObject (distributed data structure) of some kind, such as a Map.  Even the `HazelcastCacheManger` source (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-spring/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spring/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.java#L47-L58) indicates that the Spring `Cache` much exist.  One difference maybe that you created a client Hazelcast instance (line 44), which is connecting to some existing cluster where the Map is probably already defined.  Then...

Comment: It is a simple matter for Hazelcast's `CacheManager` to lookup & locate the (remote) DistributedObject ( https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-spring/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spring/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.java#L61-L71).  The diff in my configuration is that the HazelcastInstance created by Boot (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/hazelcast/HazelcastAutoConfiguration.java) is actually a embedded data node with no pre-existing data structs, anyway...

Comment: Regarding #2, have a look here (http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/outside_data_sources/sync_outside_data.html) discussing how data loaders (i.e. the `CacheLoader`) works.  Also have a look at this (http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/developing/events/implementing_write_behind_event_handler.html) to learn more about async, write-behind.  For more general info on "How Events Work" in GemFire, see here (http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/developing/events/how_events_work.html).  If you have additional questions after this, let me know.

Comment: Note (in short), with a GemFire `AsyncEventQueue` (http://data-docs-samples.cfapps.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/asyncqueue/AsyncEventQueue.html) you can both "batch" and "conflate" your entry events, so in essence, it is only writing the last update when it triggers the AEQ Listener, where you can "write-behind" to you DB.  With a `CacheLoader` it is entirely synchronous and 1-to-1 with the Region cache operation (e.g. `Region.put(key, value)`).  Hope this helps.  Read the docs and let me know.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks John :) . I have got a sample setup running (https://github.com/sandheepgr/spring-gemfire-sample). I understand that the asynctask has got batch support. Is this applicable to CacheWriter also?. I have seen an example on  your github that implements write-behind using @Async for Cache writer. In the pivotal gemfire docs, the write-behind is explained using AsyncEventListener and AsyncEventQueue. Are they different in behaviour ?